# Efficiently count reads overlapping a split feature

Tags: bioconductor, bedtools

I have a bam file with reads, and a set of features. The particularity is that some features are "split", being made of several sub-features. For example, here `bed1` and `bed2` are made of a simple feature, `bed3` contains a split feature:

```
     0        10        20
     |---------|---------|
bam   >>  
       >>>>>>>>>>>>
           >>
     |---------|---------|
bed1 ####
bed2             #####
bed3 ####        #####
```

I want to count the reads overlapping with each (set of) feature, but importantly I want to count only once a read that intersects both features in a set:

```
feature   count
   bed1       2
   bed2       1
   bed3       2   -> NOT 3
```

In R, I can do that with a GRangesList where `bed1` and `bed2` are list elements containing 1 GRange, whereas `bed3` is a list element containing 2 GRanges; find the reads that intersect a list element, then use `unique()` to avoid double-counting reads that intersect two GRanges in the same list element:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(GenomicAlignments))
exple_beds <- GRangesList(list(GRanges("I",
                         ranges =  IRanges(start = 0, end = 3),
                         strand = "+",
                         names = "bed1-a"),
                 GRanges("I",
                         ranges = IRanges(start = 12, end = 16),
                         strand = "+",
                         names = "bed2-a"),
                 GRanges("I",
                         ranges = IRanges(start = c(1,12), end = c(3,16)),
                         strand = "+",
                         names = c("bed3-a", "bed3-b")))) |>
  setNames(c("bed1","bed2","bed3"))



exple_bam <- GAlignments(seqnames = Rle(rep("I", 3)),
            strand = Rle(rep(factor("+", levels = c("+","-","*")),3)),
            pos = c(1L, 2L, 6L),
            cigar = c("2M","12M","2M"))


sapply(exple_beds,
       \(.x) findOverlaps(.x, exple_bam) |>
         to() |>
         unique() |>
         length())
#> bed1 bed2 bed3 
#>    2    1    2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However this gets really slow with a big BAM file.

So, is there

- either a more efficient way to do it in R,
- or a way to do it with bedtools and friends without creating 100,000 BED files?

Comment: For anyone reading this later, I did not find a satisfying answer and ran the above R code on subsampled bams to allow it to run in a reasonable duration (in my case it's "good enough"). An easy improvement is to parallelize the `sapply()`. For Python aficionados, I expect [RSeQC](https://github.com/MonashBioinformaticsPlatform/RSeQC/blob/master/rseqc/modules/geneBody_coverage.py) is doing something similar.